# Have all undefined routes return 404 in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm new to Symfony, and I'm working on a first project, using Symfony 4.1. I have a home page configured at '/', and that's working. The point of this project is to create a REST API, and I have a route defined at `/api/argument/`, and that's working fine, too.

However, when I navigate to `/api`, or any other route with something in the path (e.g. `/car`, `/apple`, `/something/else`), I get a 404 in the HTTP response, but the page displays a backtrace of the exception.

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

NotFoundHttpException

No route found for "GET /oijoij"
in RouterListener.php line 139
at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))in EventDispatcher.php line 212
...
```

So then in `.env` I set

```
APP_ENV=test
APP_DEBUG=0
```

And now, instead of a pretty-printed HTML backtrace, I get just a plain-text error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException in www\project\var\cache\test\srcTestProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:50 Stack trace: ...
```

How do I configure this so that undefined routes return a 404 with the 404 template page, without a backtrace?

I'm also throwing a `BadRequestHttpException` in my API controllers, and that exception just gets dumped on the page too. Does this get solved by the same method?

Comment: How to Customize Error Pages: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html. If you are throwing exceptions you could catch them in your controller and show a nice message in your template for example.

Comment: @FrankB If I am throwing an exception and catching it in the same method, why not just skip throwing the exception, and just return a response with the HTTP code and error message that I want?

Comment: Of course in your controller you just replace the throw exception line for a template call

Comment: Are you already tried set APP_ENV=prod?
Error with backtrace are visible for debugging purpose. This is configured as default for dev and test environment if you have Symfony profiler installed.

Comment: @FrankB So what are these HTTP response code exceptions, like `NotFoundHttpException`, for?

Comment: Well you should read the link i gave. A NotFoundHttpException generates a 404 page (with some kind of message). You can customize that page as well.

Comment: @FrankB So you're saying *not* to catch the exception, then?

Comment: The difference is that the error pages are a kind of global solution and when you remove the exception in your controller and instead show some kind of custom made response it will be a custom made solution for this particular situation. It depends a little bit about the circumstances.

Comment: these fancy error pages only are generated in dev environment. in prod they will be standard 404 pretty non-descriptive pages. so, essentially, you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 1):

As many people have pointed out, the error pages are generated for the `dev` and `test` environment only. In the `prod` environment, which you should use on your live system, will display a generic 404 page, which you can customize.

The system responsible for showing either the detailed error page in development or the regular 404 page in production is Symfony's event cycle, more specifically the `kernel.exception` event, which is listened to and then any uncaught errors and exceptions will be converted into an error page-response. Since you are writing an API you might want to register your own listener and return a JSON response instead of regular HTML.

An event subscriber for this could look something like this:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Api\Response;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

final class ExceptionToJsonResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        // Skip if request is not an API-request
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/api') !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        $exception = $event->getException();
        $error = [
            'type' => $this->getErrorTypeFromException($exception),
            // Warning! Passing the exception message without checks is insecure.
            // This will potentially leak sensitive information.
            // Do not use this in production!
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ];
        $response = new JsonResponse($error, $this->getStatusCodeFromException($exception));

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    private function getStatusCodeFromException(Exception $exception): int
    {
        if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
            return $exception->getStatusCode();
        }

        return 500;
    }

    private function getErrorTypeFromException(Exception $exception): string
    {
        $parts = explode('\\', get_class($exception));

        return end($parts);
    }
}
```

This will convert any exception into a JSON-response with a custom format similar to this:

```
{
    "type": "NotFoundException",
    "message": "Could not find argument with id x"
}
```

This listener will only do this for routes that start with `/api` so if you have both an API and a "regular" site it should not interfere with the default error handling.